# Assign value to 2d array in React/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a React project where i need a multidimensional constant using useState which stores +/- symbols on some condition.

`const [button, setButton] = useState([["+"]]);`

and i have the condition something like:

```
    const handleAddFields = (data_index, index, e) => {
        console.log("aaaaa!!!", data_index)
        console.log("bbbbb!!!",index)
        
        if (button[data_index][index] === "+") {

            const btn = [...button]
            btn[data_index][index] = "-"
            btn[data_index].push(["+"])
            setButton(btn)

            const btnColour = [...btnClass]
            btnColour[index] = "danger"
            btnColour.push("primary")
            setBtnClass(btnColour)

            
        } else {
            const btn = [...button]
            btn.splice(index, 1);
            setButton(btn)

            const btnColour = [...btnClass]
            btnColour.splice(index, 1);
            setBtnClass(btnColour)

            const values  = [...inputFields];
            values.splice(index, 1);
            setInputFields(values);
        }
        
    };
```

i am getting an error as

`Cannot assign to read only property '0' of string '+'` 
at
`btn[data_index][index] = "-"`
this line

The Place where the function *handleAddFields* is called is a button

`<Button name="btn" id="button" type="button" color={btnClass[data_index][index]} block onClick={(e) => handleAddFields(data_index, index, e)}>{button[data_index][index]}</Button>`

I think React does not allow assigning value to multidimensional array.
 What could be the possible solution to this?

Comment: Are you calling `setButton` from any other place? What does console.log(btn) say;

Comment: ```BTN!!! ["+"]```
This is the consol log of btn and i am not calling setButton at any other place @Codebling

Comment: Is your function even runnning once or you get this error straightaway? There has to be a place the value of `button` is changing. It is a 2D array earlier and now it is '+' or ['+'].

Comment: I tried it as `let new_btn = btn[data_index]` and `new_btn[index] = "-"`. But this also didn't worked.

Comment: its actually getting generated from:
`<Button name="btn" id="button" type="button" color={btnClass[data_index][index]} block onClick={(e) => handleAddFields(data_index, index, e)}>{button[data_index][index]}</Button>`

Comment: `handleAddFields` is the place where the condition is getting checked

Comment: Can you add complete handleAddFields code too in the question, so people coming in later know about it too without reading comments.

Comment: const handleAddFields = (data_index, index, e) => {
        console.log("aaaaa!!!", data_index)
        console.log("bbbbb!!!",index)
        
        if (button[data_index][index] === "+") {

            const btn = [...button]
            btn[data_index][index] = "-"
            btn[data_index].push(["+"])
            setButton(btn)

            const btnColour = [...btnClass]
            btnColour[index] = "danger"
            btnColour.push("primary")
            setBtnClass(btnColour)
 }
        
    };

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235076/discussion-between-arun-kumar-and-tushar-shahi).

Comment: you are copying 1st dimension with `const btn = [...button]`, not arrays inside button array. To be more clear, you should use deep copy. if button array is not modifiable, you will continue to get this error on modification.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your input is empty, try to assigning it some value

Comment: doesn't helps :(